# Creating a type alias for a templated class

Tags: c++

Instead of using

```
std::vector<Object> ObjectArray;
```

I would like it to be

```
MyArray<Object> ObjectArray;
```

with all the std::vector methods preserved. (like push_back(), reserve(), ...etc)

However, using

```
typedef std::vector MyArray;
```

won't work. Should I use template instead? How?

Comment: Could you elaborate on *why* you would want this?

Comment: @Eydne, What if he wants to change MyArray to a std::list under the hood without breaking existing code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you would really want is a templated typedef. Unfortunately those are not supported in the current version of C++, but they will be added in C++0x.

For now, here's a possible workaround:

```
template<class T> struct My {
    typedef std::vector<T> Array;
};

My<Object>::Array ObjectArray
```

Whether or not that is better than simply using `std::vector` directly, I'll leave to you to decide.

Comment: Greg, thanks for fixing my syntax. Can you tell that I've been using a lot of Java lately? ;)

Answer (score 11):

As of C++11 you can use a templated type alias

```
template <typename T>
using MyArray = std::vector<T>;
```

If you want to be more generic you can use a variadic template (which would allow for allocators in the case of vector without having to be specific)

```
template <typename... Ts>
using MyArray = std::vector<Ts...>;
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct MyArray
    :std::vector<T>
{
};

void func()
{
    MyArray<int> my;

    my.push_back(5);

    MyArray<int>::iterator i;
}
```

Compiles for me, but you may find that some things
available in vector<> need to be "pulled up"
into MyArray.

Comment: This can be a bad idea: std::vector does not have a virtual destructor. If you ever need to add a destructor to MyArray, there's a chance it might not be called.

Comment: Another problem is that `MyArray<T>` and `std::vector<T>` are different types, and overload resolution will behave differently for the two [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04d76fda15a6ae5f)