# Typedef a template class without specifying the template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef, tr1

I'm trying to typedef either an unordered_map or std::map depending whether there are TR1 libraries available. But I don't want to specify the template parameters. From what i've read so far, typedef'ing templates without arguments is not possible until official c++0x standard is available. So does anyone know an elegant workaround for this?

```
#ifdef _TR1
#include <unordered_map> 
typedef std::tr1::unordered_map MyMap; //error C2976: too few template arguments
#else
#include <map> 
typedef std::map MyMap; //error C2976: too few template arguments
#endif
```

Comment: See this very close question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544842/c-typedef-ing-stl and the provided answers. Template typedefs are not valid C++ commands

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907194/how-to-typedef-a-template-class It has another answer that's not mentioned here: "alias template" in c++11

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The way I've seen this done is to wrap the typedef in a template-struct:

```
template<typename KeyType, typename MappedType>
struct myMap
{
#ifdef _TR1
    typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<KeyType, MappedType> type;
#else
    typedef std::map<KeyType, MappedType> type;
#endif
};
```

Then in your code you invoke it like so:

```
myMap<key, value>::type myMapInstance;
```

It may be a little more verbose than what you want, but I believe it meets the need given the current state of C++.

Comment: It is indeed the usual way to simulate the lack of template typedefs in C++. However, I would have named the typedef "type" instead of "value", it seems more correct semantically speaking and it is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use full types for typedefs.

Use a #define macro instead.

Comment: Sometimes it's best to fall back on the old ways. Duct tape programming at its best.

Comment: unfortunately macros don't respect scope.