# Typedef a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have code where I want to typedef a templated class for easier reading:

```
template<int A, int B>
using templateClass = templateClass<A,B>;

void aFunction(templateClass& tc);

int main(){
    templateClass<10, 34> tc;
    aFunction(tc);
}

void aFunction(templateClass& tc){
    ...
}
```

but I get many errors regarding the template identifiers not being found. How should this be done? I was trying to follow this example:

[How to typedef a template class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907194/how-to-typedef-a-template-class)

Answer (score 6):

An *alias template* is useful when you only know *some* template parameters in advance:

```
template <class Value>
using lookup = std::map<std::string, Value>;

lookup<int> for_ints;
lookup<double> for_doubles;
```

It is unclear in your case whether you want a different name for a class template:

```
template <class A, class B>
class templateClass;

template <class A, class B>
using otherName = templateClass<A, B>;
```

if you already know the types you need:

```
typedef templateClass<int, double> int_double;
```

or if you just know one type:

```
template <class B>
using with_int = templateClass<int, B>;
```

In any case, you cannot have an alias with the same name as a class, like you're doing for `templateClass`.

Answer (score 5):

`templateClass` is not a type; it's a type template. You still need to use the `template` keyword when defining templated functions with it.

```
template<int A, int B>
void aFunction(templateClass<A, B>& tc);
```