# Template using declaration

Tags: c++, using

Why isn't it compiled:

```
template<typename T>
using v_itt = std::vector<T>::iterator; //error: missing 'typename' 
                             //prior to dependent type name 'std::vector<T>::iterator
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e15e41848f83728)

I use as it said in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6907216/2953119). What did I miss?

Comment: Where is the `typedef` in your code?

Comment: @MooseBoys What are you talking about?

Comment: your link points to *How to typedef a template class?*. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MooseBoys Have you ever read the asnwers?

Comment: No I didn't read all the answers in your link; questions on SO should generally be self-contained.  That said, it seems like your question is specifically related to [type aliasing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) in C++11.  Given that, this question probably isn't a dup of the template/typename question, but it's too low quality in its current form to justify reopening.  Odds are, you're simply not using a C++11-compatible compiler.

Comment: @MooseBoys This question is totally reasonable, and is absolutely a dup of that question...  given that the problem - as even expressed in the question itself - is the missing `typename` keyword. I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Barry looks like you're right - adding a second `template` allows the code to compile.