# using typedef for unique_ptr template

Tags: c++, templates

The following code compiles.

matrix.h before template

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    //...
    unique_ptr<Matrix<T>> Test() const;
};
```

matrix.cpp before template

```
template<typename T>
unique_ptr<Matrix<T>> Matrix<T>::Test() const
{
    unique_ptr<Matrix<T>> a{ new Matrix<T>{ 1, 1 } };
    return std::move(a);
}
```

I wanted to use a typedef (using) to shorten things as I thought it'd be more readable but my changes cause errors. Here are the relevant changes.

matrix.h after template

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    //...
    MatrixUniq<T> Test() const;
};

template<class T> using MatrixUniq = unique_ptr<Matrix<T>>;
```

matrix.cpp after template

```
template<typename T>
MatrixUniq<T> Matrix<T>::Test() const
{
    MatrixUniq<T> a{ new Matrix<T>{ 1, 1 } };
    return std::move(a);
}
```

Compiling after these changes are made crashes the VC++ compiler twice, but also generates a few errors:

```
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '<'    
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
Error   C1903   unable to recover from previous error(s);
```

What's wrong with my typedef implementation? Thanks.

Edit:
I'm using VS2015. I'm building a static library. At the bottom of matrix.cpp I have:

```
template class VMatrix<double>;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `MatrixUniq<T>` alias before having defined it.

Move the `using` inside the class:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    template<class U> using MatrixUniq = std::unique_ptr<Matrix<U>>;

    MatrixUniq<T> Test() const;
};
```

And change the definition accordingly:

```
template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::MatrixUniq<T> Matrix<T>::Test() const
{
    return MatrixUniq<T>{ new Matrix<T>{ 1, 1 } };
}
```

Or if you want to have it in the global namespace, define it before the class definition after a forward declaration on the class:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix;

template<class T> using MatrixUniq = std::unique_ptr<Matrix<T>>;

template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    //...
    MatrixUniq<T> Test() const;
};
```

Also you don't need to explicitly do a `std::move` when returning local variables. Local variables that are returned are automatically moved by default.

Comment: I think you're correct. Is there a shorter way of doing it rather than the lengthy Matrix<T>::MatrixUniq<T>. Preferably some way that other classes could see it so in other classes I could say: `MatrixUniq m = Foo();`?

Comment: @PhloxMidas See the edit I added about having it directly in the global namespace.

Comment: That compiled straight off. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    using unique_ptr_type = std::unique_ptr<Matrix>;
    //...
    unique_ptr_type Test() const;
};

template<class T> using MatrixUniq = typename Matrix<T>::unique_ptr_type;

template<typename T>
typename Matrix<T>::unique_ptr_type Matrix<T>::Test() const
{
    return unique_ptr_type(new Matrix());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. It could've gone to any of the answers, I just saw the other one first but I really appreciate your help. I gave an upvote. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Always make sure to declare templates above the code which will be using it.

Also this snippet:

```
template<class T> using MatrixUniq = unique_ptr<Matrix<T>>;

might not be a correct implementation.

Here's how you can declare a type definition in c++.

typedef <type> <var_name>
```

Here's another example using an 'Alias Template'

```
template<typename T>
using MyVector = std::vector<T, MyCustomAllocator<T>>;
```

The rest of the code is for you to debug.

See this relevant discussion here:

[How to typedef a template class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907194/how-to-typedef-a-template-class)